# filter by weekday returns empty JSON, while it should return one object for Sunday, Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

This is very very weird and I cant find a proper solution. I have a Job model That I am trying to serialize. In my view set class I have a function that filters the query set based on the day of the week. According to the documentation, weekday 6 is Sunday so the query set should have one Job in it. However it returns an empty JSON.
This is the object that should match that query:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQJNY.png)

```
   def get_queryset(self):
    day_query = self.request.GET.get('day')
    if day_query != '' and day_query is not None:
        queryset = Job.objects.filter(dt_start__week_day=day_query)
        return queryset
    else:
        today = datetime.today().weekday()
        queryset = Job.objects.filter(dt_start__week_day=today)

        return queryset
```

and this is the view set function:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5KYA.png)

If i hard code int 1 for Sunday then it works, this is quite nerve wrecking, some insight on this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please include code, not images of code: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: my bad, there you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`__week_day`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week-day) uses different values than what [**`.weekday()`** [pyton-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) returns. Indeed, if we take a look at the documentation of the `__week_day` lookup, we see:

> Takes an integer value representing the day of week from **1 (Sunday)** to **7 (Saturday)**.

Whereas the `.weekday()` returns:

> Return the day of the week as an integer, where **Monday is 0** and **Sunday is 6**.

So we will need to perform a mapping first:

```
           | mon tue wed thu fri sat sun
.weekday() |   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
__week_day |   2   3   4   5   6   7   1
```

We can perform a mapping with `((x+1) % 7)+1` where *`x`* is the result of `.weekday()`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    day_query = self.request.GET.get('day')
    if not day_query:
        today = datetime.today().weekday()
        day_query = (today + 1) % 7 + 1
    return Job.objects.filter(dt_start__week_day=day_query)
```

This might be important in case you specify a `day` parameter as well, since it of course depends on how you interpret the value.

Comment: oh man, this math equation did the trick, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I was wondering, how would you do the opposite of this? say you have the days as __week_day, but you want to revert back to .weekday()

Comment: @Nami: you can calculate this with `(x-2) % 7` with `x` the value for `__week_day`.

Comment: right thanks! this math stuff always gets me, no matter how small it is :)